# Application crashes while deleting a key from DPDK hash table

Tags: c, dpdk

I am new to DPDK trying to create a application which reads the packet information in a network and store the information in a hastable and also deletes the
information after particular timeout period. Initially I tried this in DPDK 18.02.2 version with below following details.

```
 rte_hash_parameters HashParam = {

    .name = "storing the flow in the hash table",
    .entries = 1000, 
    .key_len = sizeof(samp_flow),  
    .hash_func = ipv4_flow_hash_crc,     
    .hash_func_init_val = 0,
    .extra_flag = RTE_HASH_EXTRA_FLAGS_MULTI_WRITER_ADD,
}
```

But when tried to move from 18.02.2 to 19.11.13, facing an issue while deleting a key specifically in  rte_has_del_key(). After few debugs found out that extra flag mentioned above causes such problem.
If i remove the extra flag no issues occurs, but for my application i need this flag as simultaneously I store the flows and also delete the flows in hash table.

What am I missing here. Is there any other method where we can overcome this problem.

**Please refer the below source code**

```
/* SPDX-License-Identifier: BSD-3-Clause
 * Copyright(c) 2010-2015 Intel Corporation
 */
#include <stdio.h>
#include <pthread.h>
#include <stdint.h>
#include <inttypes.h>
#include <rte_eal.h>
#include <rte_ethdev.h>
#include <rte_cycles.h>
#include <rte_lcore.h>
#include <rte_hash.h>
#include <rte_hash_crc.h>
#include <rte_errno.h>

uint64_t counter;
pthread_t Hash_Deleting_Thrd;
struct rte_hash* tcpHashTable; 
struct ipv4_4tuple {
    uint32_t ip_src;
    uint32_t ip_dst;
    uint16_t port_src;
    uint16_t port_dst;
} __attribute__((__packed__));


#if 1
uint32_t ipv4_hash_crc(const void *data, uint32_t init_val)
{
    struct ipv4_4tuple *k = (struct ipv4_4tuple*)data;
    uint32_t *port = (uint32_t *)&(k->port_src);
    init_val = rte_hash_crc_4byte(k->ip_dst, init_val);
    init_val = rte_hash_crc_4byte(k->ip_src, init_val);
    init_val = rte_hash_crc_4byte(*port, init_val);
    return init_val;
}
#endif

void construct_ipv4_4tuple(struct ipv4_4tuple *new_key, uint32_t src_ip) {
    new_key->ip_src   = src_ip;
    new_key->ip_dst   = 178430105; //10.162.160.153
    new_key->port_src = 60000;
    new_key->port_dst = 80;
    printf("%lu %lu %u %u\n",new_key->ip_src, new_key->ip_dst,new_key->port_src,new_key->port_dst);
}

/*
 * The lcore main. This is the main thread that adds a key to the DPDK hashtable */

void lcore_main(void)
{
    struct ipv4_4tuple key;
    int ret,i = 0;
    uint32_t ip_src = 168430105; /*10.10.10.25*/
    void *data_ptr = NULL;
    
    for(;;)
    {
    /*Form IPv4_4tuple to calculate hash_key*/
    construct_ipv4_4tuple(&key, ip_src + i);

     ret = rte_hash_lookup_data(tcpHashTable, (const void *)&key , (void **)&data_ptr);
    if(ret < 0 )
    {
        ret = rte_hash_add_key_data(tcpHashTable, &key,(void *)data_ptr);   
        if(ret != 0) { 
            printf("Key Adding Fails %d %d %d\n",ret,EINVAL,ENOSPC);
        }
        else {
            counter++;
            printf("*************New Key Added counter:%lu********** \n",counter);
        }
    } 
    sleep(1);
    i++;
    }
}

/* This thread deletes the added key */

void lcore_main2(void)
{
    struct ipv4_4tuple key;
    int ret,i =0 ;
    void *data_ptr = NULL;
    uint32_t ip_src = 168430105; /*10.10.10.25*/

    for(;;) {
    /*Form IPv4_4tuple to calculate hash_key*/
    construct_ipv4_4tuple(&key,ip_src + i);

    ret = rte_hash_lookup_data(tcpHashTable, (const void *)&key , (void **)&data_ptr);
    if(ret >= 0) {
    ret = rte_hash_del_key(tcpHashTable, (const void *)&key);
        if(ret < 0 )
        {
            printf("Key Deleting Fails %d %d %d\n",ret,EINVAL,ENOSPC);
        }
        else {
            counter--;
            printf("*************Key Deleted  counter:%lu*********\n",counter);
        }
    }
        i++;
        sleep(1);
    }
}
/*
 * The main function, which does initialization and calls the per-lcore
 * functions.
 */
int
main(int argc, char *argv[])
{
    /* Initialize the Environment Abstraction Layer (EAL). */
    int ret = rte_eal_init(argc, argv);
    if (ret < 0)
        rte_exit(EXIT_FAILURE, "Error with EAL initialization\n");

    argc -= ret;
    argv += ret;
    if (rte_lcore_count() > 1)
        printf("\nWARNING: Too many lcores enabled. Only 1 used.\n");

        struct rte_hash_parameters tcp_hash_params = {
        .name = "Hash Table for TCP",
        .entries = 10,
        .key_len = sizeof(struct ipv4_4tuple),
        .hash_func = ipv4_hash_crc,
        .hash_func_init_val = 0,
                //.extra_flag = RTE_HASH_EXTRA_FLAGS_RW_CONCURRENCY,/*No support in dpdk-18.02*/ 
                .extra_flag = RTE_HASH_EXTRA_FLAGS_MULTI_WRITER_ADD, 
    };

        tcpHashTable = rte_hash_create(&tcp_hash_params);
        if(tcpHashTable == NULL)
          printf("Unable to create Hash Table\n");
        else
          printf("Hash Table created with %d entries %d\n",tcp_hash_params.entries,rte_errno);


/* launch the lcore_main on the 1st core. */
    rte_eal_remote_launch(lcore_main, NULL, 1);

    if(0 == pthread_create(&Hash_Deleting_Thrd, NULL, lcore_main2, NULL))
    {
        printf("Created hash deletion thread\n");
    }
    else
        printf("Unable to create key deletion thread");

    while(1)
        ;;

    return 0;
}
```

**"Also refer the debug information that were obtained while executing the source code in DPDK version 18.02.2 and 19.11.13"**

```
    "Compiled source code in DPDK-19.11.13 and verified"

[root@localhost ~]# gdb ./basicfwd
GNU gdb (GDB) Red Hat Enterprise Linux 7.6.1-120.el7
Copyright (C) 2013 Free Software Foundation, Inc.
License GPLv3+: GNU GPL version 3 or later <http://gnu.org/licenses/gpl.html>
This is free software: you are free to change and redistribute it.
There is NO WARRANTY, to the extent permitted by law.  Type "show copying"
and "show warranty" for details.
This GDB was configured as "x86_64-redhat-linux-gnu".
For bug reporting instructions, please see:
<http://www.gnu.org/software/gdb/bugs/>...
Reading symbols from /root/basicfwd...done.
(gdb) r -c3 -v
Starting program: /root/./basicfwd -c3 -v
[Thread debugging using libthread_db enabled]
Using host libthread_db library "/lib64/libthread_db.so.1".
EAL: Detected 8 lcore(s)
EAL: Detected 1 NUMA nodes
EAL: RTE Version: 'DPDK 19.11.13'
[New Thread 0x7ffff6a7f700 (LWP 3228)]
EAL: Multi-process socket /var/run/dpdk/rte/mp_socket
[New Thread 0x7ffff627e700 (LWP 3229)]
EAL: Selected IOVA mode 'PA'
EAL: Probing VFIO support...
[New Thread 0x7ffff5a7d700 (LWP 3230)]
EAL: PCI device 0000:00:19.0 on NUMA socket -1
EAL:   probe driver: 8086:153a net_e1000_em
EAL: PCI device 0000:01:00.0 on NUMA socket -1
EAL:   probe driver: 8086:10fb net_ixgbe
EAL: PCI device 0000:01:00.1 on NUMA socket -1
EAL:   probe driver: 8086:10fb net_ixgbe
EAL: PCI device 0000:02:00.0 on NUMA socket -1
EAL:   probe driver: 8086:1533 net_e1000_igb

WARNING: Too many lcores enabled. Only 1 used.
Hash Table created with 10 entries 2
168430105 178430105 60000 80
*************New Key Added counter:1***********

[New Thread 0x7ffff527c700 (LWP 3231)]
Created hash deletion thread
168430105 178430105 60000 80

Program received signal SIGSEGV, Segmentation fault.
[Switching to Thread 0x7ffff527c700 (LWP 3231)]
0x0000000000651ef4 in __rte_hash_del_key_with_hash ()
Missing separate debuginfos, use: debuginfo-install glibc-2.17-326.el7_9.x86_64 libgcc-4.8.5-44.el7.x86_64 libpcap-1.5.3-13.el7_9.x86_64 numactl-libs-2.0.12-5.el7.x86_64
(gdb) bt
#0  0x0000000000651ef4 in __rte_hash_del_key_with_hash ()
#1  0x000000000055e68c in lcore_main2 () at /home/basicfwd.c:97
#2  0x00007ffff7bc6ea5 in start_thread () from /lib64/libpthread.so.0
#3  0x00007ffff6d94b0d in clone () from /lib64/libc.so.6


Above debug explain that when the source code is compiled in 19.11.13, In one thread a key is added to DPDK hash table and in another thread tries to delete the key. 
When it tries to delete, the code crashes. 


"Compiled source code in DPDK-18.02.2 and verified"

[root@localhost ~]# gdb ./basicfwd
GNU gdb (GDB) Red Hat Enterprise Linux 7.6.1-120.el7
Copyright (C) 2013 Free Software Foundation, Inc.
License GPLv3+: GNU GPL version 3 or later <http://gnu.org/licenses/gpl.html>
This is free software: you are free to change and redistribute it.
There is NO WARRANTY, to the extent permitted by law.  Type "show copying"
and "show warranty" for details.
This GDB was configured as "x86_64-redhat-linux-gnu".
For bug reporting instructions, please see:
<http://www.gnu.org/software/gdb/bugs/>...
Reading symbols from /root/basicfwd...done.
(gdb) r -c3 -v
Starting program: /root/./basicfwd -c3 -v
[Thread debugging using libthread_db enabled]
Using host libthread_db library "/lib64/libthread_db.so.1".
EAL: Detected 8 lcore(s)
EAL: RTE Version: 'DPDK 18.02.2'
EAL: Multi-process socket /var/run/.rte_unix
[New Thread 0x7ffff6a7f700 (LWP 3912)]
EAL: Probing VFIO support...
[New Thread 0x7ffff627e700 (LWP 3913)]
[New Thread 0x7ffff5a7d700 (LWP 3914)]
EAL: PCI device 0000:00:19.0 on NUMA socket -1
EAL:   Invalid NUMA socket, default to 0
EAL:   probe driver: 8086:153a net_e1000_em
EAL: PCI device 0000:01:00.0 on NUMA socket -1
EAL:   Invalid NUMA socket, default to 0
EAL:   probe driver: 8086:10fb net_ixgbe
EAL: PCI device 0000:01:00.1 on NUMA socket -1
EAL:   Invalid NUMA socket, default to 0
EAL:   probe driver: 8086:10fb net_ixgbe
EAL: PCI device 0000:02:00.0 on NUMA socket -1
EAL:   Invalid NUMA socket, default to 0
EAL:   probe driver: 8086:1533 net_e1000_igb

WARNING: Too many lcores enabled. Only 1 used.
Hash Table created with 10 entries 0
168430105 178430105 60000 80

*************New Key Added counter:1**************

[New Thread 0x7ffff527c700 (LWP 3915)]
Created hash deletion thread
168430105 178430105 60000 80
*************Key Deleted  counter:0**************

168430106 178430105 60000 80
*************New Key Added counter:1**************

168430106 178430105 60000 80
*************Key Deleted  counter:0**************

168430107 178430105 60000 80
*************New Key Added counter:1**************

168430107 178430105 60000 80
*************Key Deleted  counter:0**************


But when the source code is compiled in 18.02.2 no issues are identified as one thread adds a key and another thread deletes it.
```

Comment: please either share code snippet or DPDK example to reproduce the error. Also always share the relevant  DPDk eal args, and information on huge pages, platform, whether it is 32 or 64 Bit. Please update the necessary information to reproduce the error. If you have a backtrace or core dump that will help too. (note always reproduce the error in bare minimum example for easier debug)

Comment: Hi vipin I tried 64 bit centos 7.6 machine, regarding your query i will shortly post the snippet with obtained error

Comment: `I tried 64 bit centos 7.6 machines` not clear, platform means `x86, powerpc, arm with 64bit or 32 bit binary?

Comment: Hi @VipinVarghese I have posted the source code and debug information while my code crashes. Kindly provide your suggestions.

Comment: Yes it is tested in x86_64 machine with DPDK eal args -c3 -v

Comment: can you please explain the reason for using `pthread_create` for running `Hash_Deleting_Thrd`. You are aware not all Thread Local Storage (which is used the libraries) can not be used.  Did you try running with `rte_remote_launch with desired core id`

Comment: the issue is identified and explained, the solution is also. Simple debug with GDB explains the issue, please make use of the tools. Please accept and upvote to close the ticket.

Comment: the problem is reproduced, analyzed, and explained with solution is also shared. Please acknowledge the same by accepting and upvoting, this will help others if they face similar issue too.

Comment: as there is no issue (confirmed over live debug), please accept and upvote to close the question. this will help others too.

Answer (score 0):

As mentioned in the comments, the Hash Library uses TLS (Thread Local Storage) to access lcore-specific buckets and fill entries. Using Pthread to launch the `Hash_Deleting_Thrd` will not supply the necessary id (lcore_id) with the good value which results in the ***segfault***.

Steps used to Debug:

1. rebuild the DPDK Library and application with `-ggdb3`
2. use gdb to pinpoint the issue with `gdb --args ./a.out --no-pci`
3. run the application in gdb interactive mode with `run`

[image]

checking lcore-id returns

[image]

this indeed is wrong for `lcore_id`.

[how to solve the problem]

There are 3 major problems with the code shared

1. use of threads and not dpdk lcore threads for DPDK libraries which rely on DPDK TLS data
2. incorrect ordering for call of support function result context switch fo r lcore main threads
3. use of `while(1)` which prevents the run of dpdk main threads when options for `-l or -c` is shared.

A simple fix of the code below solves these 3 problems as

```
#if 0
/* launch the lcore_main on the 1st core. */
    rte_eal_remote_launch(lcore_main, NULL, 1);

    if(0 == pthread_create(&Hash_Deleting_Thrd, NULL, lcore_main2, NULL))
    {
        printf("Created hash deletion thread\n");
    }
    else
        printf("Unable to create key deletion thread");

    while(1)
        ;;
#else
unsigned lcore_id  = rte_lcore_id();
lcore_id = rte_get_next_lcore(lcore_id, false, false);
rte_eal_remote_launch(lcore_main2,NULL, lcore_id);

lcore_main();
rte_eal_mp_wait_lcore();

#endif
```

Result: Moving the function to use DPDK pthread, results in the right value for TLS lcore id. Thus heap-delete functions properly without any hiccups.

[image]

[edit-1] add screenshot to the comment `delete thread is not called`

[image]

[Edit-2] based on the live debug, the `lcore_main2` is actually running on the desired lcore. the reason why lcore_main2 print is because

1. both add & delete is started from the initial counter  `uint32_t ip_src = 168430105; /*10.10.10.25*/`
2. with remote launch first delete thread is started then add thread. The causes catch up where delete is running ahead of add.

***Solution: either add thread synch or add sufficient delay or logic to ensure add is started first.***

**hence claim delete thread is not running is incorrect.**

Comment: Hi Vipin thanks for the comment but when I implemented your fix in the code deletion thread (lcore_main2) was not working which was done by remote launch whereas addition API (lcore_main) was working fine. What migth be the issue here.

Comment: what do you mean `deletion therad is not working`?

Comment: Delete thread is indeed called and functioning, please recheck

Comment: @Vijayraagavan still waiting to hear from you, can you please explain why delete thread is not working for you via call?

Comment: Sure Vipin we can have a call. Can you provide your available time slot after 6 in the evening,  which will be useful to schedule.

Comment: My sincere apologies @Vipin Varghese due to heavy rainfall in my location had electricity issues which got restored just now. Kindly let me know if we can reschedule meeting tomorrow at 12pm if possible, else provide your available time slot so that I can reschedule. Also I might need your email ID to send an invite.

Comment: Thanks for the session @Vipin Varghese. Regarding rte_thread_set_affinity(), this API supports both EAL and NON-EAL thread and also update TLS. Will it also update TLS for non-EAL threads? please refer the link for more info about the API https://doc.dpdk.org/api-19.11/rte__lcore_8h.html#acee8af58733d20040049958864a22596

Comment: @Vijayraagavan this is not related to the question asked in StackOverflow. So I recommend to close the question by accepting the same since the claims of thread not running is not true. With respect your colleague who was over phone, I have clearly said I am not able to understand her question and requested for diagram. I have shared the thread safe API calls too. I am not even clear what are asking me refer. `if you think it works use it, please do not combine and add new ideas `.